# Edit or Delete current table row by clicking href link in the same row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am building my HTML table as follows

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="rqstLines" id="rqstLines" width="90%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th>
        <th>Order Qty</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
    var ProductCode = $( "#ProductCode option:selected" ).val();
    var productcode = $( "#ProductCode option:selected" ).text();
    var qty = document.getElementById("OrderQty").value;

    var table=document.getElementById("rqstLines");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    row.id = "tr-"+tblcounter;
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);

    cell1.innerHTML=productcode;
    cell2.innerHTML=qty; 
    cell3.innerHTML='<a href="#" onClick="editTable();">Edit</a>';  
    cell4.innerHTML='<a href="#" onClick="deleteRow();">Delete</a>';

    tblcounter++;
```

Here is my deleteRow()

```
function deleteRow() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

But I am unable to delete the row, even when I try to get the text from current table row's td, it is returning as null, see below:

```
alert( $(this).parent().siblings(':eq(0)').html() );
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code from

**this**

```
      cell4.innerHTML='<a href="#" onClick="deleteRow();">Delete</a>';
```

**to**

```
     cell4.innerHTML='<a href="#" onClick="deleteRow(this);">Delete</a>';


  function deleteRow(obj) {
    $(obj).closest('tr').remove();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your function is the `window` not the element which was clicked. You need to pass the reference in:

```
cell4.innerHTML='<a href="#" onClick="deleteRow(this);">Delete</a>';

function deleteRow(el) {
    $(el).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function deleteRow() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: $(this).parent() will be <td>, not <tr>